problem in collision detection in c (raylib)
for some reason if rec1 touches rec2 it teleports.
Rec1 is the player and rec2 is an object. I want rec1 not to go inside rec2. When rec1 collide with rec2 stop it moving forward. Same for up, down, left, right.
// It would be great if u can suggest me different way to do this.
#include "raylib.h"

int main() {
    const int screenWidth = 800;
    const int screenHeight = 450;

    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "Rectangle Collision Example");
    SetTargetFPS(60);

    Rectangle rec1 = { 100, 200, 50, 50 }; // Initial position and size for rec1
    Rectangle rec2 = { 400, 200, 50, 50 }; // Initial position and size for rec2

    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
        // Move rec1 based on arrow keys
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_LEFT)) rec1.x -= 2;
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_RIGHT)) rec1.x += 2;
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_UP)) rec1.y -= 2;
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_DOWN)) rec1.y += 2;

        // Check collision between rec1 and rec2
        if (CheckCollisionRecs(rec1, rec2)) {
            // Adjust rec1 position to prevent overlap
            if (rec1.x + rec1.width > rec2.x)
                rec1.x = rec2.x - rec1.width;
            if (rec1.x < rec2.x + rec2.width)
                rec1.x = rec2.x + rec2.width;
            if (rec1.y + rec1.height > rec2.y)
                rec1.y = rec2.y - rec1.height;
            if (rec1.y < rec2.y + rec2.height)
                rec1.y = rec2.y + rec2.height;
        }

        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);

        DrawRectangleRec(rec1, BLUE);
        DrawRectangleRec(rec2, RED);

        EndDrawing();
    }

    CloseWindow();
    return 0;
}


Please elaborate "teleports".

Your code moves first, then checks and tries to undo, if I am not mistaken. Did you consider checking first and then only move if OK?

Did you do a few examples with pen and paper? I suspect that the behaviour you describes results logical from your code, because your guessing of what got you into the forbidden area is off and your attempt to fix moves into the wrong direction. I think it could be described as "teleports" if it approaches from the right and then gets fixed to the left of the forbidden area. So please gibe much more detailed examples of what you observe and describe what of that does not match your understanding of your code.

@Yunnosch if the rec1 touches the top left side of rec 1 it teleport rec1 to top of he rec2 same with every corner

Please provide example input values which cause what you describe, along with the result which you observe and in contrast to that the result you expect. Try with pen and paper what you expect your code to do and note where the values you get differ from what you expect or what your code results. Do not forget to include the keys needed to get the result you observe. Maybe identify that of your four ifs you expect to trigger in each of your examples and explain why you expect it instead of the one which causes the jump as observed.
